# Is there any way I can duplicate a QOpenGLWidget without redrawing it?

Tags: python, qt, opengl

I have a high poly object drawn in a QOpenGLWidget, and I want to do a feature so when I press a key this widget is drawn on another window, and the other one to be left in the back (so still visible). So I would need a way to duplicate it, without redrawing, because redrawing a high poly object takes time. Is there a way I can achieve this?

Comment: The OpenGL solution can be [`glReadPixels`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glReadPixels.xhtml)

Comment: Can you give me some more information on using this function?

Comment: Re. `glReadPixels`: a more convenient way of invoking it in this particular case would be to simply call [`QOpenGLWidget::grabFramebuffer`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qopenglwidget.html#grabFramebuffer).